# i am not able to map the api data array i have tried several methods from last two days

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Here is the simple code which fetches api recipes and prints them as cards :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import RecipeItem from "../../components/recipe-item";
import Search from "../../components/search";

const Homepage = () => {
  const [loadingstate, setloadingstate] = useState(false);

  const [recipes, setrecipes] = useState([]);

  const getdatafromsearchcomponent = (searchdata) => {
    setloadingstate(true);

    async function getrecipes() {
      const apiresponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=2aa0ee8853c34e1f9783e0f882c40f38&query=${searchdata}`
      );
      const result = await apiresponse.json();
      const { results } = result;

      if (results && results.length > 0) {
        setloadingstate(false);
        setrecipes();
      }
      console.log(result);
    }
    getrecipes();
  };

  console.log(loadingstate, recipes, "loadingstate recipes");


  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <Search getdatafromsearchcomponent={getdatafromsearchcomponent} />

      {loadingstate && (
        <div className="loadingmsg">loading.... please wait</div>
      )}
      {
       recipes && recipes.length>0?
       recipes.map((item)=>           /*THIS PART IS NOT WORKING*/
       <RecipeItem  item={item} />)
       :null
       }
    </div>
  );
};
export default Homepage;
```

recipe-item component below :

```
const RecipeItem=(props)=>{
    console.log(props,'recipe-item-props');
    return(
        <div>
            search result
        </div>
    )
}
export default RecipeItem;
```

I am trying to map the recipes i fetched from spoonacular api its fetchinf fine and shows data in the console but does not work when i try to map it on homepage

I tried to merge the search component to the homepage but that also did not work.

even the loading part is working fine the api fetch loading text shows on homepage but once the fetch over no data is visible on mapping although the fetched data is clearly visible on the console

and sorry for posting the entire code almost.

Comment: Nobody will debug your app for you.
- Simplify code as much as possible, post only a minimal snippet to demonstrate the problem.
- Write where is the problem, what is the expected behavior/result and what is the actual behavior/result. Nobody knows what "does not work" mean.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're just calling `setrecipes` without any value

Comment: its not an app  its an course on udemy which i was trying

Comment: You haven't pass prop to the <RecipeItem/> element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your code I can see that you are destructuring results but not set in the setrecipes properly, you have to set it like this setrecipes(results) after setloadingstate(false); inside the if condition.